# Multiple select options, but reverse the order of one option

Tags: angularjs

I have a select element that has 2 options. Created_at and Release_date. These options sort the order of the ng-repeat in the view. So when I select created_at the list gets ordered from first to last created, when I select release_date it orders the list from first release date to the last.

I would like to add a inverse to the `created_at` option. Because I want the record that's been created last to be the first record in the list. But I don't want to change the order of the `release_date` list.

```
$scope.select = function(){
  orderByClick = this.selectedItem.value;
  orderBy();
}

var orderBy = function(){
  var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
  $scope.movies = orderBy($scope.movies, orderByClick);
  console.log('orderBy')
}
```

I've created a plunker with the select option, http://plnkr.co/edit/HCncjLYyPD0EiyHFDOs9?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="descendingOrder"> Descending?

$scope.movies = $scope.descendingOrder ? orderBy($scope.movies, orderByClick) : $scope.movies.reverse();
```

Comment: Not completly, I didn't want to add a checkbox. Just when the function was called. But I created a if/else statement like so, http://plnkr.co/edit/HCncjLYyPD0EiyHFDOs9?p=preview seems to work.